# Confusing SPDT Toggle Switch footprint

Tags: spdt

I am looking at this [datasheet](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Toggle-Switches_YUEN-FUNG-MT-0-102-C003-N003-RS_C1788495.html).

It is a simple SPDT switch, but it has 5 pins in the footprint instead of 3.
Since I am using it as a power on/off switch, I wired it up like below.

[image: switch]

I want to make sure it is correct use of this.

Thank you.

Comment: Yep, that looks right to me. Pins 4 and 5 are optionally used for shrouding. You might want to ground Pin 3 btw just to make sure you don't get any unwanted behavior or static buildup by leaving it unconnected.

Comment: @InBedded16 Do you mean pins 4,5 grounded? Because grounding pin 3 would short out the input power as soon as the switch is turned off, probably not exactly what we want.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ope yes, yes I did. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'extra' two pins are connected to the metal housing and switch handle:

[image]

[image]

They are for mechanical mounting. Typically you might leave them to float, connect them to earth or connect them to circuit ground. Up to you (though they provide a direct connection to the user's fingers, so safety is a consideration in some applications).

Answer (score 1):

`4`-`5` are mechanical pins for mounting the switch securely to the PCB, you can optionally connect the mounting pins  to ground if you want the handle to be grounded, else leave them unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

If the pins are numbered correctly, then it is correct. The two pins are just for mechanical support.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a photo of the switch or a link to a datasheet.

The other two pins might be mounting pins to relieve mechanical stress on the signal pins and assure correct position alignment.  If what you have is a right-angle, pcb-mount toggle switch, then that is what they are.

The two pins are connected through the body of the switch, but should not be used as an electrical connection.  If the switch protrudes through a panel that is important for shielding, connect the mounting pins to the same GND potential as the panel so the switch's mounting frame "plugs up" the hole it is poking through.